# Chai: Check if any array item is true using 'expect'

Tags: javascript, testing, chai

I need to check if `[boolean,boolean,boolean]` array contains only `true` using specifically `expect` from `chai`.

On stackoverflow I found solution with `should` keyword, but I am only allowed to use `expect` 
As I found out from docs we can use `expect(result).to.eql([true, true, true])` 
But what if we have array with length 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
expect(result).to.eql(new Array(result.length).fill(true));
```